# I want the pattern for removing the &b=128&f=norefer from following url

Tags: java

`http://www.yahoo.com &b=128&f=norefer`

I want to remove `&b=128&f=norefer`

```
String finalUrl =decodedUrl.replace("&b=128&f=norefer", "");
                page.setPageUrl(finalUrl);
```

I have used this code but I want code without hardcoded `&b=128&f=norefer`  in code

Comment: So what exactly do you want to have removed? Everything after first &? Or only the `b` and `f` parameters? BTW, the URL doesn't seem to be a complete one.

Comment: where is the ? in the url where the querystring begins ?

Answer (score 1):

you should be using URL object of java for this : 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost()
[search for getHost() method in it.]

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason for not wanting a hardcoded string that you wish to be able to remove some other string as well? Then you could consider writing a method like:

```
public String removeNoise(String url, String noisePattern) {
    return url.replace(noisePattern, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex replacement to remove everything after the first ampersand:

```
"http://www.yahoo.com &b=128&f=norefer".replaceAll("&.*$", "");
```