# I want the regular expression for removing the &b=some value

Tags: java

I have the url http://www.yahoo.com;b=&90

I want to remove the b=&90 without hardcoading value

```
String finalUrl =decodedUrl.replace("&b=90","");
                page.setPageUrl(finalUrl);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want the pattern for removing the &b=128&f=norefer  from following url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931398/i-want-the-pattern-for-removing-the-b-128f-norefer-from-following-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your URL looks like http://www.yahoo.com&b=90 and you wish to remove all parameters use the following code snippet: `url.replaceFirst("&.*", "")`. 
If you wish to remove the parameter b only and do not want to remove other parameters that may be before and after taking into consideration that the parameter may be the first, last and in the middle the regular expression will be more complicated and requires some debugging. Please say if you need this and I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To replace parameters called *b* that aren't the first parameter, you could try:

```
&b=.+$
```