# hi I want the code for &b=52&f=norefer and &b=52

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want the pattern for removing the &b=128&f=norefer  from following url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931398/i-want-the-pattern-for-removing-the-b-128f-norefer-from-following-url)

```
http://www.yahoo.com/url/5f&b=52&f=norefer 
http://www.yahoo.com/url/6aa82d?show=all&page=2&b=52 

String finalUrl =decodedUrl.replace("&b=52","");
page.setPageUrl(finalUrl);
```

I want to remove `&b=52&f=norefer` from the first url and `&b=52` and from the second url which pattern i will use please give me the code without hard-coded value.

Comment: Asking the question several times won't help you. It only annoys the community, esp. you have already been given some answers.

Comment: 1. Avoid asking duplicate questions. 2. Write clearly worded questions so they are easy to understand. This way you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

`url.replaceFirst("&b=.*", "");` will remove the tail of the string starting from "`&b=`". I hope it is good enough for you. At least it is OK for your two exampels and is not sensitive to value of parameter b.

If it is not enough try to describe your task more specifically or just learn a little bit regular expressions.

Comment: please don't reward the OP's rudeness.  If you want to answer, please answer the original question, not the repost.